# Listview filtering from SQL Server on combobox selection

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, listview, combobox

How do I filter my listview out from the combobox selection example.

If the user selects the items `5*108` in the combobox then the list view will show all the items that have that `5*108` in it which is in the `P.krydsmål`

C#

```
     public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    string connStrings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sql"];
    string Data = @"Select   ps.Mærket AS Mærke, P.DataID, P.Billed, P.Model, P.Årgang, P.[Motor Type], P.Krydsmål, P.Centerhul, P.ET,P.Bolter, P.Dæk, P.Fælge ,PS.Krydsmålene from Data.Hjuldata P  inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.MærkeID = PS.MærkeID ORDER BY ps.Mærket";
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _selectedParam;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
BindData()
ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(hjuldata.ItemsSource);
            dataView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Mærke"));

    }
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    public string SelectedParam { get { return _selectedParam; } set { _selectedParam = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedParam"); if (_selectedParam == "ingen") { BindData(); } else { hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori().Tables[0].DefaultView; ; } } }
    private void BindData()
    {
        hjuldata.ItemsSource = kategori().Tables[0].DefaultView;

    }
    public DataSet kategori()
    {
        //SQL statement to fetch entries from Hjuldata
        DataSet dsdata = new DataSet();

        //Open SQL Connection
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
        {
            conn.Open();

            //Initialize command object
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Data, conn))
            {                
                SqlDataAdapter adapters = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                //Fill the result set
                adapters.Fill(dsdata);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return dsdata;
    }
    public DataSet FilterKategori()
    {

    string Data = @"Select ps.Mærket AS Mærke, P.DataID, P.Billed, P.Model, 
P.Årgang, P.[Motor Type], P.Krydsmål, P.Centerhul, P.ET,P.Bolter, 
P.Dæk, P.Fælge ,PS.Krydsmålene from Data.Hjuldata P  
inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.MærkeID = PS.MærkeID 
WHERE Krydsmål = @param1";//only works with  '5*108'





//SQL statement to fetch entries from products
            DataSet dsdata = new DataSet();

            //Open SQL Connection
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
            {
                conn.Open();

                //Initialize command object
                using (SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(Data, conn))
                {
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", SelectedParam);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapters = new SqlDataAdapter(cmds);
                    //Fill the result set
                    adapters.Fill(dsdata);
                }

            }
            return dsdata;
        }
```

Combobox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_Copy" Width="150" Height="40" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" Background="#FF303030" FontSize="16"  Canvas.Left="1030" Canvas.Top="24" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTest2}"  SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedParam, ElementName=win, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Ingen"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="3x98"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="3x112"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="4x98"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="4x100"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="4x108"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="4x114.3"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="4x160"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="5x98"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="5x100"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="5x108"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have showed the debug value of SelectedParam, I got the problem. The problem is in combobox. Your combobox should be something like:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_Copy" Width="150" Height="40" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" Background="#FF303030" FontSize="16"  
       SelectedValuePath="Content"
       SelectedValue = "{Binding SelectedParam, ElementName=win, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Ingen"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="3x98"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="3x112"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="4x98"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="4x100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="4x108"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="4x114.3"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="4x160"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="5x98"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="5x100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="5x108"/>

</ComboBox>
```

Notice the SelectedValuePath. This will send to SelectedParam the string not the object ComboBoxItem.

See a demo in my github: [DemoCombo](https://github.com/quicoli/StackOverflow-37103043)

Please, pay attention to the names, mine can be different of yours...

Comment: thats worked so now i just have to figure out how to get the grouping to work with this but at least it solved my question

Comment: it give me this when i trying it with grouping 
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The parameterized query '(@param1 nvarchar(4000))Select ps.Mærket AS Mærke, P.DataID, P.B' expects the parameter '@param1', which was not supplied.

Comment: this messagem 'expects the parameter '@param1', which was not supplied' says you have a parameter defined in your SQL sentence, but you dont have provided a value for it.

Comment: yeah the value is null in  SelectedParam not exactly sure how to fix that

Comment: is that something that i have to provide in the sql management?

Comment: Now I'm lost. What is not working? First filtering is working or not? If you select  "3x98" is it working?

Comment: filtering working fine but when i trying to group it with `private void BindData()
        {
            hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori().Tables[0].DefaultView;

        }`  then it don't and says that SelectedParam is null when i do it wih `hjuldata.ItemsSource = Kategori().Tables[0].DefaultView;` instead then filtering works but the grouping don't

Comment: for grouping you have to use other SQL sentence. I suggest you to open a new question where you share the scenario again, since you have things working now... describe your screen, etc... So this could help us to understand better :)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the use of a MVVM pattern, to make things easier for you. But as you are using code behind:

1- Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your Window:

```
public class MainWindow: Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  //Existing code....


  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
  {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
      }
  }
}
```

2 - Define a property representing the selected item in you combobox and in its setter, you can trigger your filter method:

```
private string _selectedParam;
public string SelectedParam 
{
  get{return _selectedParam;}
  set
  {
     _selectedParam = value;  
     NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedParam");
     hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori(_selectedParam).Tables[0].DefaultView;

  }
}
```

3 - Bind ComboBox SelectedItem to your new property:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_Copy" 
          SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedParam, ElementName=YourWindowsName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Width="150" Height="40" 
          Foreground="#FF00FB0B" Background="#FF303030" FontSize="16"  
          Canvas.Left="1030" Canvas.Top="24">
     <ComboBox.Resources>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="#FF303030" />
     </ComboBox.Resources>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Ingen"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="3*98"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="3*112"/>
</ComboBox>
```

4 - Create your FilterKategori

```
public DataSet FilterKategori()
{

string Data = @"SELECT [DataID], [MærkeID], [Billed], [Model], [Årgang], [Motor Type], [Krydsmål], [Centerhul],
    [ET], [Møtrikker], [Bolter], [Dæk], [Fælge]
FROM 
    [OminiData].[Data].[Hjuldata]
WHERE
    Krydsmål = @param1";

//SQL statement to fetch entries from products
DataSet dsdata = new DataSet();

//Open SQL Connection
using (SqlConnection conns = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
{
conns.Open();

//Initialize command object
using (SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(Data, conns))
{
   cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", SelectedParam );
   SqlDataAdapter adapters = new SqlDataAdapter(cmds);
   //Fill the result set
  adapters.Fill(dsdata);
}

}    
return dsdata;
}
```

Comment: seems like that could be the solution how do i make it when the ingen is chosed then it will show all the items instead of filtering it and what about multiple filtering if i wan't to also filtering it even more from another combobox

Comment: "Ingen" means "all" ?  okay. Just verify what was chosen:

public string SelectedParam 
{
  get{return _selectedParam;}
  set
  {
     _selectedParam = value;  
     NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedParam");
     if (_selectedParam == "ingen")
    {
        BindData();   
    }
   else
  {
     hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori(_selectedParam).Tables[0].DefaultView;
   }
  }
}

Comment: Now, about the filtering even for, you can use the same principle

Comment: i getting a error when changin out public partial class to public class Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MainWindow'; another partial declaration of this type exists and a no overload for method FilterKategori takes 1 argument i had updatet my question with what i have done

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I had mistyped Window declaration. 
You don't need to remove "partial"... as I said, you must implement INotifyPropertyChanged:  public partial class MainWindow: Window, INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: i thougth so :) but do you know why i getting the ` no overload for method FilterKategori takes 1 argument` on `public string SelectedParam { get{return _selectedParam;} set { _selectedParam = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedParam"); if (_selectedParam == "ingen") { BindData(); } else { hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori(_selectedParam).Tables[0].DefaultView; } } }`

Comment: In the setter, change  hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori(_selectedParam).Tables[0].DefaultView;  to  hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori().Tables[0].DefaultView;

Comment: that fixed it but it doesn't work even if i put in hjuldata.items.clear(); nothing happends

Comment: That should work. Please, debug the Setter. Verify if the following line is being executed: hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori(_selectedParam).Tables[0].DefaultView;

Comment: this is what i got >         public string SelectedParam { get{return _selectedParam;} set { _selectedParam = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedParam"); if (_selectedParam == "ingen") { BindData(); } else { hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori().Tables[0].DefaultView; ; } } }
. 
(1,50): error CS0103: The name '_selectedParam' does not exist in the current context
(1,73): error CS0103: The name '_selectedParam' does not exist in the current context

Comment: after digging abit deeper in it i think the problem is in the xaml as
 i getting this error Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Mainwindow'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedParam; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=comboBox_Copy); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')

Comment: 'ElementName = MainWindow ' is the name of you Window, defined in XAML, so if in you Window you had set:  Name = "Window1", should be: ElementName = Window1

Comment: arh alright that was the reason it didn't fired up since i know getting the error on the statement
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '@param1'.

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: Please,  check the sql sentence.

Comment: alright fixed the sentence but nothing is showed up in the list with `@param1` but if i do change `@param1` out in the `WHERE` to `'5*108'` then it will shows up all the items with 5*108 and so on is like it dont convert the param1 to the value of the selected items

Comment: Insert a breakpoint in this line cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", SelectedParam ); and check selectedparam value.

Comment: thats seems to be fine `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: ingen`

Comment: see my next answer